# Move multiple values from column which has multiple rows in a different column Power BI or Excel

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to move the data from one column which has distinct values in rows but the other column has same values in rows as shown in the pitcure.

I am new to power BI, can someone please help on this?

Thank you in advance

[Req](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lV2j.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following two measures - using `CONCATENATEX()`

```
Col_1 = CONCATENATEX(Your_Table,Your_Table[Col1]&";")

Col_2 = CONCATENATEX(Your_Table,Your_Table[Col2]&";")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Power BI, you can perform some **Transformation** in **Power Query Editor** to achieve your required output.

**Let**, your table structure and sample data looks as below-

[image]

**Now**, go to **Advanced Editor** for your table and replace the code with this below code-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("PcdJDoAgEETRu/TaSyCoKDjPEu5/Dbs0qcVP/ktJjBTitENy8avSTqrWLqrRbsprz6dSr9WMITuwJANoyQg6sgcrcgDrj1Z3BBtyAj05gy25gB25goHcwEjuYC85vw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [col1 = _t, col2 = _t, col3 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"col1", type text}, {"col2", type text}, {"col3", type text}}),
    
    //--New Transformation starts from here
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"col1"}, {{"grouped", each _, type table [col1=nullable text, col2=nullable text, col3=nullable text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each [grouped][col2]),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each [grouped][col3]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Extracted Values1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Values", {"Custom.1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values1",{"grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Here is the final output-

[image]